# Launching function on pyspark executors without arguments

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I can't find information about the case when the function is invoked over broadcasted objects in spark like this without arguments (everything is on the executors already):

```py
df_b = spark.sparkContext.broadcast(pandas_df)
def function_running_on_each_executor():
   data = df_b.value
   # some processing
   df.groupby('id').sum() # and so on
   #...
   # submit it to the ML model and get predictions
```

I can do it only if I use some auxiliary rdd

```py
empty_cols_for_test = []
spark.sparkContext.parallelize(empty_cols_for_test, 1).mapPartitions(function_running_on_each_executor)
```

and redefine the function as

```py
def function_running_on_each_executor(cols):
   data = df_b.value
   # some processing
   df.groupby('id').sum()
```

Is there optimal way to implement this? Basically, I want to apply different sklearn models with different parameters to a single dataset on every executor

Comment: Spark has a low-level job submission mechanism but that still runs on RDDs. Perhaps the easiest solution would be to create a dataset (or an RDD) with model kind and parameters in the rows and then run `map` or `mapPartitions` on it.

Comment: Got it, I try it